# FreeSerif font more condensed after update to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I am writing a book using LibreOffice. Until recently I used Ubuntu 12.04 and LibreOffice 3.5.7.2. The body text of the book is typeset with FreeSerif 11pt. Before my upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 and LibreOffice 4.2.6.3 (which came with 14.04), the book had 210 pages. After the upgrade the book has 195 pages, because the FreeSerif font now was more condensed.

When I open the odt file in a different computer with Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 and LibreOffice 3.5.7.2, the book has 210 pages, and so it has when I open the same file in a computer with Windows 7 and LibreOffice 4.2.6.3 the book has 210 pages. (Of course the Free* fonts are installed in all computers.)

So with 14.04 and 4.2.6.3 the FreeSerif font is rendered differently. The difference is big, about 7%, which makes the text look ugly, and the line breaks and the hyphenation have been changed, not to say ruined.

Obviously, there is something wrong with the rendering of the FreeSerif font in the combination of Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 and LibreOffice 4.2.6.3. Will this error be corrected?

Comment: Just a friendly note: AskUbuntu uses a syntax called Markdown, and in Markdown, you need to make two line breaks for a paragraph. Just one line break will be rendered as a space.